# Smooth movement in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I made a very simple engine that basically draws a character and then you can move it around the screen.

But I did the movement in quite a horrible way, I mean it is based on discrete values like this:

```
void Scene::movePlayer(int dir) {

    switch (dir){
    case 1:     yy = yy + 0.05;
            break;

    case 2:     xx = xx - 0.05;
            break;

    case 3:
            yy = yy - 0.05;
            break;

    case 4:
            xx = xx + 0.05;
            break;

    default:
            break;
}
```

it works and moves the character, but I don't really like it since it's very jumpy and it isn't smooth.

I'd love to have more smooth movement, just like in mario or something like that.

Could you tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you thinking of *acceleration/deceleration*, as opposed to the discrete "stop/move" you currently have?

Comment: It would be nice but it's not what I am currently focusing on. 

Basically now, the 0.05 value outputs a significant "jump" between two positions that is easily noticeable. When I reduce this value the movement is smoother (because the jumps are much shorter) but it also makes the character move much slower (because to travel a set distance there's a larger amount of "jumps" required.)

I don't know how to balance it out so that the character would move reasonably quick through the screen but also it make it in really tiny jumps so it looks smooth.

Comment: This is a framerate issue.  The faster the framerate, the smaller the movement step can be in order to get from A to B in the same time period.  So how are you detecting that a character should move and redrawing the scene?

Comment: I just have a function that detects input:
`
void Keyboard(int key, int x, int y) {

 switch (key)
 {

 case GLUT_KEY_UP:  s.movePlayer(1);
       break;
 case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
       s.movePlayer(2);
       break;
 case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
       s.movePlayer(3);
       break;
 case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
       s.movePlayer(4);
       break;
 default:
       break;
 }
 glutPostRedisplay();
}`

and thats it. The game doesn't do anything when there's no input because I don't know how to make it so the game would still continue doing something (let's say animate background or something) when there's no input

Comment: You need to set the velocity to some value when key is down and to zero when the key is released, i.e. handle both the down and up messages and then apply this amount to the position in your main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is *acceleration* (and maybe deceleration as well – let me think about that while answering).

The steps to follow are these:

1. your Mario is standing still at position `x`. Set `speed` to `0.0` and `acceleration` to a small value, such as `0.01`.
2. user presses the <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> key. Add `acceleration` to `speed` and update his position. Make sure the acceleration has the correct sign – negative for moving left, positive for moving right.
3. as long as the user does not release the key, keep adding `acceleration` to `speed` – but stop as soon as `speed` reaches a suitable value (your `0.05`, for example).
4. If you want Mario to *slide to a halt* when the key is released, set `acceleration` to a negative value such as `-0.015` (usually more than when accelerating), and use it to *decrease* the speed until it is less or equal to `0.0`. When it's less, make sure to reset it to *exactly* `0.0`! Floating point operations are inaccurate, and a very small remaining value may make your Mario keep moving ever so slightly.

This procedure is *strongly tied* to the actual timing of your entire game loop. You need to add or subtract the `acceleration` only once per game frame.
You *can* make it work with variable update intervals (that is, adjust the speed depending on the time between two successive `speed` updates) but it's easier to start with a fixed frame rate, such as 25 or 50 frames per second. That way the `acceleration` can be constant; the right value can be estimated by trial runs. I imagine you ended up with your `xx = xx + 0.05;` like that through the same process.

The same procedure can be used for "jumping" and "falling". To jump, set the initial speed to a high value and decrease it in every game loop. Don't worry if it falls below `0`, that is necessary to have what went up go down again. To fall, set the speed to `0.0` and increase it using `acceleration` again.

This will work fine if your Mario moves along an infinite straight line. You then only have to keep an eye on his `yy` position – it may not extend below the 'floor'. If you are going to add different vertical levels to move on, you can add a collision check for both moving left and right (make it a dead stop instead of sliding to a halt) and for moving up and down (again, a dead stop if he jumps up and knocks his head on something, but then followed by 'falling', and an increasing speed if he walks off of something, until he hits a block at the bottom).

Comment: Thank you very much that helps a lot. Could you please tell me how to limit framerate in my program? So far, it runs the same on my brand new gaming pc and really old weak laptop so I guess it's not really a massive issue now, but I'd like to know for the future reference.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is using `glutTimerFunc` – put your speed and position updates in its callback function. A `msecs` value of 40 (see [its description](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gluttimerfunc)) ought to give you round and about 25 fps.